# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiNtg.png)

please help me, why error like this?
see pic in above, i run my code and import this library.

`import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
   from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
   from txws import WebSocketFactory
   import json`

Comment: Please don't link to externally hosted content containing information critical to the interpretation of your question.  Externally hosted content disappears.  Copy the traceback from the terminal as text and include it in your question.

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered similar problems, is installed in the MAC when running scrapy:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 38, in <module>
TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
AttributeError:'module'has no attribute object'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
```

My solution is to re install the twisted version specified by the program, such as the scrapy I installed:

```
sudo pip install twisted==13.1.0
```

Finally I succeeded

```
~ scrapy
scrapy 1.3.3 - no active project
```

Comment: I ended up having to do `pip install 'twisted<17'` because another package needed the logging module in Twisted.